# Jquery not working every page if I write it in cakephp default ctp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

In cakephp default layout page I have linked Jquery in Head tag. Before body tag in default.ctp I have added below code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     alert('hello');
  })
</script>
```

After click on left sidebar,It's working only in home page not in every page.Here I have create separate element for left sidebar.

Comment: remove the single quote around `'document'`

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the browser's web inspector tools?

Comment: I have the same issue did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

**Note:- Remove quotes with document object.**

Comment: Here it's working in home page, so I don't think it's happening for single quote, however I have tried your code it's giving me same result.

Answer (score 0):

Place the script in the default layout page in the footer